# Buffering characteristics of Unix Sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, buffering, unix-socket

Does anyone know the buffering characteristics of Unix sockets when sending small chunks of data (a few bytes)?

When I am using TCP sockets, I can disable the Nagle algorithm to prevent latency in data transit. But there's no equivalent functionality (that I know of) for Unix Domain sockets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no nagle algorithm available on unix domain sockets.

Unix sockets are normally implemented as a memory buffer in the operating system kernel. Once you've written/sent data on the socket, it is copied into that buffer, and becomes immediately available to the peer.

Comment: Right. It's not specified exactly how quickly though in POSIX; that's system specific. Linux, for example, guarantees that you get data out immediately: if you call `write` on a non-blocking socket, and then `read` the other end immediately, it promises to return the data. I haven't read the docs for all the common unixes, but I've written code with that assumption and it's run fine on Solaris, Darwin, AIX, FreeBSD, HP-UX too, so it seems safe to rely on it. Please correct me if I'm wrong though!

Comment: @NicholasWilson I don't see any reason why data that has been written wouldn't be available immediately on any platform.