# localsocket server not receiving readyread signal

Tags: linux, qt, linux-kernel

I have a QLocalserver where I read data sent by a non QT client. The data is sent after receiving some keyevents. This means if I press some key, the data is sent through localsocket to server and I have to perform some action in my server.

Now it happens at times that the data does not reach the server even when the return value of sendto is +ve value i.e. success. The data is received only when any other key is pressed even though if I am not sending the data to socket after that.

I am reading for all bytes till end in while loop in my readyread slot, but stil don't know what the problem is. Can anyone help me in figuring this out. Is this related to ready read signal genration or some scheduling problem.

The Ready read slot is as below

```
void MainWindow::ReadyRead(void)
{
  char cmd[sizeof( struct Data)];
  struct Data *Rcv;
  while(ui->client->bytesAvailable())
  {
    ui->client->read(cmd, sizeof(struct Data));
    Rcv= ( struct Data *)cmd;
    CommandParser(Rcv);
  }
}
```

Comment: Another suggestion: I think running a loop within the ReadyRead-slot is not really recommended (as far as I know), better if you just check for bytesAvailable and append them (the amount of bytes returned by the function) to a byte-array handled by yourself. Moreover the whole read may fail, assume the number of bytesAvailable() is smaller than "sizeof(Data)"

Answer (score 0):

W/o some piece of code it's hard to cleary say whats wrong, I've some assumptions:

1. Since the data seems to be very small, it may be that the socket (client) is buffering the data up to a specific amount, thus not sent. See "**Nagle**"-algorithm...
2. Do you have a endless-loop in your "readyRead"-slot? That could lead to problems while receiving the data.

A piece of code would be appreciated, though.

Comment: Everytime the data sent is a structure of 32 bytes.  The only loop in my ready read is for checking bytesAvailable() as shared in the code snippet above.

Comment: Is bytesAvailable() == 0 or is there any data pending? Try to disable the Nagle-algorithm at the client side, do you get there any different result?

Comment: Hey Robert I am using localsocket which is similar to Unix socket, will Nagle-algorith still be applicable?. Often I receive the data and bytesAvailable() returns proper. The interesting factor is if I am using only command line option to interface the client application to the server to display some information on LCD, things work fine but as soon as I bring the switches in picture things become unpredictable. I verified the switch modules are fine but some the behavior that just pressing the switch and not calling the API to send the data also results the data to be received at server.

Comment: Is there any related documentation regarding the localsocket, cant find anything. The nagle-algorithm is a mechanism to reduce the TCP overhead (send one big packet instead of multiple smaller ones). For Unix-Sockets it is not available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010033/buffering-characteristics-of-unix-sockets